# Testing cron module

Tags: magento-1.7, module, cron

having a module that just run through cron, can I test it without firing the cron process?
I installed `AOE scheduler` but even if I select the process and run it, I've to wait for the cron scheduling.

Is there any solution to run it like calling an url, bypassing the cron process?

thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

The best way to test cron methods in any new controller action. There is no difference between method, which executes by cron and any other observer method.

You can create your own controller (or use any existing controller and temporarily call there this action).

**Following solution is not very clean. Purpose of this solution only understand what do you need:**

For example there is ProductController.

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php

This controller has many different actions, like viewAction, etc... You can create any new action like `cronAction` and put there your call there:

```
Mage::getModel('yourmodulename/observer')->yourCronMethod();
```

Don't forget to write your existed module, class and method names. After that call in browser

> http://host/catalog/product/cron

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out Magerun https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Really simple to get installed and set up.

You can run cron jobs direct from CLI, have a read of the git page theres loads of tasks that will save you a shed load of time.

Runninf a cron job is as simple as

n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run [job]

You can also see all cron jobs by running

n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:list

Answer (score 1):

To test a cron manually, set up crontab in your `config.xml` every minute  like this

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mysample_cron_auto>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>namespace_module/observer::methodName</model>
            </run>
        </mysample_cron_auto>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

To now test this cron, you can go to your browser and run `www.yourMagentoPath/cron.php`.

You can `die` here and check the execution of the observer method.

**P.S.** Make sure you do not have any other cron that runs every minute, otherwise there are chances of conflict.

**EDITED**

To by pass the cron process,

Create a file `test.php` inside your magento root folder and write the code in that file and then execute it with below URL http://www.yourdomain.com/test.php

Comment: I think is the same to run it through AOE schedule, what i'd to do is to bypass cron process. thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: can't, as is a really complex module, not just one file. I guess I've to create a controller to initialize the module and bypass the cron process