# What is the cron job that cancels the expired orders? Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I know that magento has cron jobs by default for specific tasks, I need the cron job to cancel unprocessed orders that have a time greater than 48 hours. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your custom module to run cron job. I have explain you how to do this

1. create/open your module config.xml file and put below code in

To run a cron job every 48 hours.The fields denote (from left-to-right):Minute, Hour, Day of Month, Month, Day of Week. The "*/2" in the Day of Month field means "every two days".

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cancelorder_Cron>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Cancelorder_Cron>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Cancelorder_Cron>
                <class>Cancelorder_Cron_Model</class>
            </Cancelorder_Cron>
        </models>   
    </global>           
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <Cancelorder_Cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 2 */2 * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>Cancelorder_Cron/cron::cancelUnprocessedOrders</model>
                </run>
            </Cancelorder_Cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

2. create/open your module model file Cancelorder/Cron/Model/Cron.php And add below code

> ```
> <?php 
> class Cancelorder_Cron_Model_Cron 
> {   
>     public function cancelUnprocessedOrders($observer)
>     {                 
>       $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
>       ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT))
>       ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
>       $orders ="";
>         foreach($orderCollection->getItems() as $order)
>             {
>               $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
>               $orderModel->load($order['entity_id']);
>
>
>               if(!$orderModel->canCancel())
>               continue;
>
>               $orderModel->cancel();
>               $orderModel->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
>               $orderModel->save(); 
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: And can I call this cron through the browser to test?

Comment: Yes you can . please review this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78715/testing-cron-module . and update your code

Comment: What is my cron code? to test the cron??

Comment: Where can I create the module? some specific directory?

Comment: Create in local code pull folder .